# How can i barplot a dataframe contains character an numeric in R?

Tags: r, rgraph

I have this data frame

```
product Total
AF064   21
AF065   24
AF066   1
AF067   13
AF068   6
AF069   3
AF070   5
AF071   1
AF072   3
AF073   3
AF074   5
AF075   2
AF076   28
AF077   0
AF078   3
AF079   10
AF080   0
AF081   13
AF082   0
AF083   3
AF084   3
AF085   2
AF086   3
AF087   0
AF088   1
AF089   1
AF090   2
AF091   4
AF092   2
AF093   3
AF094   2
AF095   3
AF096   1
AF097   2
AF098   2
AF099   1
AF100   21
AF101   1
AF102   3
```

I want to make barplots from this dataframe.

My code is

```
barplot(product,Total)
**Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator**
```

I also tried

```
barplot(dataframe)
**Error in barplot.default(dataframe) : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix**
```

I've also tried `as.character` for the product but still can't do the graph. 
I really appreciate your help guys, much thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt was almost right,

```
attach(dataframe)
barplot(Total,names.arg=product)
```

would do it.

Another possibility, is to turn the df into a matrix and feed it to the `barplot()` function.

The `barplot()` function will draw a bar for each column of the matrix, so you need to transpose the immediate conversion of the dataframe

```
m <- t( matrix(dataframe[,2],dimnames=dataframe[1]) )
barplot(m)
```

In case you have multiple columns (e.g. 2 to 3) in your data frame you can put all of them in the matrix, as rows:

```
m <- t(as.matrix(dataframe[,2:3]))
colnames(m) <- dataframe[,1]
barplot(m,legend=T)
```

As for your last comment, you could turn the labels sideways and resize them a little bit. I.e. using directly the dataframe

```
 attach(dataframe)
 barplot(Total,names.arg=product,cex.names=0.6,las=2)
```

or using the matrix `m`

```
 barplot(m,cex.names=0.6,las=2)
```

Comment: this helps a lot too, now i have all the names of each bars on the X-axis . Thanks for all your correction, i only knew a bit of these R functions, but now i knew better . really appreciate the help !

Answer (score 1):

You want the parameter of barplot to be a vector of height. You can use something like this:

```
barplot(dataframe[,2], names.arg=dataframe[,1])
```

Comment: Yes, i got the graph right ,much thanks for the help. but the X-Axis didnt show each product in one graph. how can i show them all without extending the graph?